# What does "a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments)" mean?

Tags: javascript, apply, call, bind

Just because of curiosity I wanted to make a bounded function with this particular approach :

```
var fn = function(a, b, c) {
    return a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments)
}

var boundFn = function(a, b, c) {
    fn.apply(null, arguments)
}

function unboundedFn() {
    console.log(this, arguments)
}

var boundedFn = boundFn(unboundedFn, x, y);
```

So I'm trying to understand what a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments) do exactly ?

Comment: Is this code you wrote or code you found? It's flawed either way - `fn` returns a function but `boundFn` doesn't do anything with the return value it. So, the code is a very over-the-top way of wasting CPU cycles.

Comment: This is the real code I'm trying to understand : 

kaa = function(a, b, c) {
    return a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments)
}
laa = function(a, b, c) {
    //
}
D = function(a, b, c) {
    Function.prototype.bind && -1 != Function.prototype.bind.toString().indexOf("native code") ? D = kaa : D = laa;
    return D.apply(null, arguments)
};

i get it from youtube js code

Comment: `a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments)` is a cumbersome way to write [`a.bind(b, c)`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or `a.bind(Array.from(arguments).slice(1))` (`b` and `c` are never used, so remove them from the parameter list).

Comment: @SebastianSimon It's cumbersome but it's the only way to do a variadic call with ES5. The rest of the code also keeps to this spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have a function like this:

```
function unboundedFn() {
    console.log(this, arguments)
}
```

You can use `unboundedFn.call(thisObj, arg1, arg2)` or `unboundedFn.apply(thisObj, [arg1, arg2])` to run it, but changing what `this` means inside. Both `call` and `apply` do the same, and only difference is way of passing arguments.

Becouse `call`, `apply` and also `bind` are methods, you can run for example `unboundedFn.call.call.call.call.apply.apply.apply.apply()`, but it doesn't seem to have to much sense.

In your example `return a.call.apply(a.bind, arguments)` is equal to `return a.bind.call(...arguments)`, which is equal to `a.bind(...arguments.slice(1))`, so whole fn function can be simplified to:

```
function fn(a,b,...args){
   return a.bind(b, ...args);
}
```